# Drupal 7.27: 408 Request time out in Chrome browser

Tags: .htaccess, http-request

We are getting 408 request time out errors in Chrome browser only since the beginning of May. We have not been able to replicate the problem with any other browser. With one website we had a SSL protocol and the error only occured in Chrom on http://
After implmenting a redirect from http:// to https:// via .htaccess the error seemed to have gone.
On a second site there is no SSL certificate and the error only occurs occasionally but it does. We have set the request_time_out to 10080 in the php.ini to no avail. Another thing we tried: We redirected that site to be accessed only with "www".

Has anyone experienced something similiar? Any suggestions would be very welcome.

Comment: What your server's logs says about it? Are requests made by Chrome in any way different than those by other browsers? Do you have any browser-detection code? As for *"Any suggestions would be very welcome"* - no. This site is **not a forum**, it is for **answers**, so please ask your question as something that can have definitive answer, like "what's the cause" or "how to prevent that", or something. It should be relatively easy in this case.

Comment: If my questions do not sematically fit your expectations than have my apologies. Of course I wanted to know the cause but was not sure whether it was a problem limited to my installation or a general problem so I phrased my question with best intentions. And it was not relatively easy to detect as the bug only occurs on Chrome browsers with an http:// protocol and HAProxy running on the server. The solution is easy, though: errorfile 408 /dev/null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a Chrome bug.

https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/208790/408-request-time-outs-still-continues/232275#232275

One solution: http://blog.haproxy.com/2014/05/26/haproxy-and-http-errors-408-in-chrome/

Seems to be limited to Chrome, page requests through http:// and servers running HAProxy.